# Image Problem in Chat Application not visible in

Tags: swift, image, uikit, chat

I'm working on a chat application using [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) where I'm trying to display images in the chat messages. The images are loaded asynchronously, but I'm facing an issue where the images are not visible in the UI.

I've implemented the MessagesDataSource protocol and created a custom cell named `CustomMessageCollectionViewCell` to handle the display of images.

The images are loaded using an asynchronous function named `loadImageForMessage`, and I'm using a placeholder image if the URL is nil.

```
// Message struct conforms to MessageType

extension Message: MessageType {

    var kind: MessageKind {
        if let imageUrl = imageUrl, let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
            let mediaItem = MediaItem(url: url, image: nil, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder_image_name") ?? UIImage(), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))

            return .photo(mediaItem)
        } else {
            return .text(content ?? "")
        }
    }
```

```
// CustomMessageCollectionViewCell
     func configure(with message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) {
        guard case let .photo(media) = message.kind else {
            return
        }

        if let imageUrl = media.url {
            print("MediaItem URL: \(imageUrl)")
            messageImageView.isHidden = false

            messageImageView.loadImage(from: imageUrl) {
                print("Loaded")
            }
        } else {
            print("MediaItem URL is nil")
            messageImageView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    // ... (existing code)
}
```

```
// ChatViewController
        if case let MessageKind.photo(mediaItem) = message.kind, let imageUrl = mediaItem.url {
            loadImageForMessage(message as! Message) { updatedMessage in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.messageImageView.image = updatedMessage.image
                    messagesCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)])
                }
            }
        }
```